# Using Apache Commons for first time, HashBag.uniqueSet() returning wrong object type?

Tags: java, apache-commons

I'm using Apache Commons for the first time, mainly because I wanted access to their HashBag class.  I'll outline the entire process I've followed to help pinpoint the problem.

First, I downloaded current version (3.2.1) of the Apache Commons Collections.
http://commons.apache.org/collections/download_collections.cgi

Then I extracted the file `commons-collections-3.2.1.jar` to a folder on my disk, and added that folder to my system `%CLASSPATH%` environment variable so that I could import classes into my Java programs.

This test program illustrates the problem I'm having.

```
import org.apache.commons.collections.bag.HashBag;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashBag test = new HashBag();
        System.out.println(test.getClass().getName());
        System.out.println(test.uniqueSet().getClass().getName());
    }
}
```

The first output line says `org.apache.commons.collections.bag.HashBag` which is expected.

The second output line says `org.apache.commons.collections.set.UnmodifiableSet` which is NOT expected.  According to the doc [HERE](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/bag/HashBag.html), the `uniqueSet()` method is inherited from both a superclass and an interface, but in both of those cases the method is supposed to return a `java.util.Set`.  Why is it returning something different here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no problem at all, `org.apache.commons.collections.set.UnmodifiableSet` implements `java.util.Set`.

A function with a given return statement can return descendants of the specified class. Otherwise, it would not be possible to use interfaces and abstract classes as return types...

That's OOP at its finest :)

Comment: That does make sense, thanks.  But the real problem for me is that I wanted to cast the returned set to a HashSet<HashSet<String>>, and it's not letting me because it is "unmodifiable."

Comment: No, no. This is not because it is non-modifiable! Why would you cast it to HashSet? What would that provide more to you then a simple Set?

HashSet is an implementation. You should not tie your code to implementations, use the interface where applicable.

So if you had to cast to HashSet, because you wanted to return HashSet from a function, the return type should be Set instead of HashSet...

Comment: But the contract of the method states, that it should return an unmodifiable Set: http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/bag/AbstractMapBag.html#uniqueSet%28%29

Comment: @The111 your main problem is using a specific class. Java **doesn't work like that**. The finest thing in OOP is programming to interfaces, not to implementation classes. In the end, you should use a `Set<YourClass>` instead of `ClassThatImplementsSetInterface<YourClass>`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza is right, maybe his words are a bit clearer than mine...

Comment: Yeah, I think I've got a handle on it now.  Thanks for your comments everybody, they really helped. :-)

Answer (score 2):

`org.apache.commons.collections.set.UnmodifiableSet` implements `java.util.Set` so everything looks ok. A method must return a concrete implementations hiding under an interface!